# Python, need help in making 'brute force' using mechanize

Tags: python, url, mechanize, brute-force

I'm playing with mechanize
Trying to make a brute force for MY website
I'm just wondering how to check if the form was submitted successfully

so far:

```
import mechanize
import cookielib
import urllib
import HTMLParser
import re
# Browser
br = mechanize.Browser()

# Cookie Jar
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)

url = 'http://mywebsite'
pattern = '''Welcome (.*)'''

passwords = ('lol','lol1','correctPassword')

r = br.open(url)
try:
    br.select_form(nr=0)
    br.form['username']='Matt'
    found = False
    i=0
    while not found:
        br.form['password']=passwords[i]
        # here I want to check if br.submit() was successful 
        # than break the loop (or simply make found = True)
        # if not, increment i
        br.submit()
except:
    print "Not Good"
html = br.response().read()
message = re.findall(pattern, html)

parser = HTMLParser.HTMLParser()
print parser.unescape(message)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar question. And there is no documentation on it.
If not already known. I suggest you use br.click()

I checked the error by looking at error elements on the webpage.
Something like this

```
request = br.click(name='login')
 response = br.open(request)
 mainpage = response.read()
 if mainpage.find('<the error text>')==-1
        #print "Could not login"
        success = True
```

Hope this helps